# Is there a way to detect if a web camera is already denied in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There are two cases for asking permission for the web camera:

1. No permission, need to ask user for permission, user will see
   allow/deny popup
2. No permission, allow/deny popup cannot be shown
   (at least on chrome) because user has previously denied

I know I do not have permission because I inspect `DeviceMediaInfo.label`.  Is there a way to distinguish between the two cases?

Use case execution paths

1. Warn user that app is about to ask permission, then ask
   permission Code path
2. Go directly to 'please change your browser
   settings to allow camera'

Comment: Why would one ask twice?

Comment: Why do you want to see if the user denied permission?  Isn't it enough that permission is denied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect it with the  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()  method and inspect the device.label for null